# Listing all columns for one employee (dept, emp, salgrade)

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join, select

I am using Emp/Dept data base from ORACLE. Here is the structure if someone doesn't know it:

```
 CREATE TABLE EMP
           (EMPNO NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
            ENAME VARCHAR2(10),
            JOB VARCHAR2(9),
            MGR NUMBER(4),
            HIREDATE DATE,
            SAL NUMBER(7, 2),
            COMM NUMBER(7, 2),
            DEPTNO NUMBER(2));

    INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
            (7369, 'SMITH',  'CLERK',     7902,
            TO_DATE('17-MAR-1980', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),  800, NULL, 20);
    INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
            (7499, 'ALLEN',  'SALESMAN',  7698,
            TO_DATE('20-MAR-1981', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 1600,  300, 30);
    INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
            (7521, 'WARD',   'SALESMAN',  7698,
            TO_DATE('22-MAR-1981', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 1250,  500, 30);
    INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
            (7566, 'JONES',  'MANAGER',   7839,
            TO_DATE('2-MAR-1981', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),  2975, NULL, 20);
    INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
            (7654, 'MARTIN', 'SALESMAN',  7698,
            TO_DATE('28-MAR-1981', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 1250, 1400, 30);
    INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
            (7698, 'BLAKE',  'MANAGER',   7839,
            TO_DATE('1-MAR-1981', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),  2850, NULL, 30);
    INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
            (7782, 'CLARK',  'MANAGER',   7839,
            TO_DATE('9-MAR-1981', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),  2450, NULL, 10);
    INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
            (7788, 'SCOTT',  'ANALYST',   7566,
            TO_DATE('09-MAR-1982', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 3000, NULL, 20);
    INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
            (7839, 'KING',   'PRESIDENT', NULL,
            TO_DATE('17-MAR-1981', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 5000, NULL, 10);
    INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
            (7844, 'TURNER', 'SALESMAN',  7698,
            TO_DATE('8-MAR-1981', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),  1500,    0, 30);
    INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
            (7876, 'ADAMS',  'CLERK',     7788,
            TO_DATE('12-MAR-1983', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 1100, NULL, 20);
    INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
            (7900, 'JAMES',  'CLERK',     7698,
            TO_DATE('3-MAR-1981', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),   950, NULL, 30);
    INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
            (7902, 'FORD',   'ANALYST',   7566,
            TO_DATE('3-MAR-1981', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),  3000, NULL, 20);
    INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
            (7934, 'MILLER', 'CLERK',     7782,
            TO_DATE('23-MAR-1982', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 1300, NULL, 10);

    CREATE TABLE DEPT
           (DEPTNO NUMBER(2),
            DNAME VARCHAR2(14),
            LOC VARCHAR2(13) );

    INSERT INTO DEPT VALUES (10, 'ACCOUNTING', 'NEW YORK');
    INSERT INTO DEPT VALUES (20, 'RESEARCH',   'DALLAS');
    INSERT INTO DEPT VALUES (30, 'SALES',      'CHICAGO');
    INSERT INTO DEPT VALUES (40, 'OPERATIONS', 'BOSTON');

    CREATE TABLE SALGRADE
            (GRADE NUMBER,
             LOSAL NUMBER,
             HISAL NUMBER);

    INSERT INTO SALGRADE VALUES (1,  700, 1200);
    INSERT INTO SALGRADE VALUES (2, 1201, 1400);
    INSERT INTO SALGRADE VALUES (3, 1401, 2000);
    INSERT INTO SALGRADE VALUES (4, 2001, 3000);
    INSERT INTO SALGRADE VALUES (5, 3001, 9999);
```

I need to list in one query all columns for one employee (let's say KING). Everything would be easy but there is the Salgrade table that I don't know how to link with others...
I was trying something like this but it doesn't work...

```
SELECT e.Empno, e.Ename, e.Job, e.Mgr, e.Hiredate, e.Sal, e.Comm, e.Deptno, d.Dname, d.Loc, s.Grade
FROM Emp e, Salgrade s
INNER JOIN Dept d ON d.Deptno=e.Deptno
WHERE e.Ename = 'KING' AND e.Sal BETWEEN s.Losal AND s.Hisal
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track with the join on inequality conditions on `Salgrade`. however you should *never* mix implicit and explicit joins. Their order of evaluation is different, so this leads to hard-to-debug failures. Your query yields error:

> `ORA-00904: "E"."DEPTNO": invalid identifier`

Matter of fact, *always* use standard, explicit joins (with the `on` keyword).

This should do it:

```
SELECT e.Empno, e.Ename, e.Job, e.Mgr, e.Hiredate, e.Sal, e.Comm, e.Deptno, d.Dname, d.Loc, s.Grade
FROM Emp e
INNER JOIN Dept d ON d.Deptno=e.Deptno
INNER JOIN Salgrade s ON e.Sal BETWEEN s.Losal AND s.Hisal
WHERE e.Ename = 'KING'
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1881d2ab90512440d7f71de9788cd71a)**:

```
EMPNO | ENAME | JOB       |  MGR | HIREDATE  |  SAL | COMM | DEPTNO | DNAME      | LOC      | GRADE
----: | :---- | :-------- | ---: | :-------- | ---: | ---: | -----: | :--------- | :------- | ----:
 7839 | KING  | PRESIDENT | null | 17-MAR-81 | 5000 | null |     10 | ACCOUNTING | NEW YORK |     5
```